# Communicate between Devices through WiFi with known IP address

Tags: java, android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

Now I am developing an Android application that has communication between a teacher and a student in which the student connects to the teacher using the teacher's IP Address and the teacher sends data to student with the student's IP address. Can this done with WiFi peer-to-peer?
I don't want to search for devices, because I already have the IP address of the other device.
What is the best I should do this?

Comment: If they are able to communicate across the network then you could use a TCP socket or any other transport like HTTP. Depends what your sending I guess.  I havent played with broadcast packets on Android since before 4.0 and back then UDP was not working from a handset.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that with Wi-Fi Direct. Check out Android's developer page on [Wi-Fi Peer-to-Peer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html). Then you can transfer data with sockets, without connecting to a network.

```
WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;
mManager.connect(mChannel, config, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        //success logic
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int reason) {
        //failure logic
    }
});
```

Here are some other [Wi-Fi Direct resources](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wi-fi-direct/uWpuOzHY6y0) if you are interested.